# MySQL MATCH AGAINST not find results if an underscore is attached to the search term

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, match-against

I use full text indexing to find results faster and it works well except when the term i search for **is attached to an underscore inside the database record**.

---

My database records:

```
article.title
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

My article 123456 created
------------------------------
My article new_123456 created
------------------------------
My article 123456_new created
```

---

My match against query:

`MATCH(article.title) AGAINST ( "123456*" IN BOOLEAN MODE )`

---

This query return only the first record and ignore the others since the term **"123456"** is attached to **an underscore ( _ )**, either before or after the term, the query will ignore the records.

What is the thing I did wrong and how to fix this problem?

Comment: you can't fix, use `LIKE '%123456%' `

Comment: @nbk thank you for your reply, but why this happen in the first place? it's weird that full text search can't find the result since the underscore can be anywhere in any text like usernames. Like is good but very slow for large data sets (millions or records), it will take x10 time more than the fulltext search.

Comment: Full Text searches have rules and it can't find anything like new_123456 with the search term 123456, read the manual in its entirety to understand the limits

Comment: @nbk thank you so much, I already make a research about it and I was hoping to find a workaround or an alternative method with same performance.

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: hello @RickJames, I use innoDB

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can mess up FULLTEXT:

- Punctuation
- "stop words"
- min word "length"
- Language

It is sometimes best to edit the data before storing it.  In your case, replacing `"_"` with `" "` might be the 'right' solution.  That could be done either in your application code as you insert strings, or by using MySQL's `REPLACE()` as the string is `INSERTed`.